# How to combine countpct and binomCI into the same summary statistic to be used in tableby function?

Tags: r, function, statistics, summary

I'm using the `tableby` function from the `arsenal` package to create summary tables. For most of the statistics I need to generate, this package gives me exactly the format I'm asked except for one. I need to get in the same cell something like this:

> n (%) [95%CI of the percentage]

For now, I'm using the `countpct` function which gives me the "n (%)" and `binomCI` which gives me the proportion with 95%CI but it doubles the number of rows in my final table so it's not ideal...

How could I do to have everything on the same line ?

I tried to see if I could create another function from the original ones but I don't really understand their syntax...

Thanks for your help.

---

EDIT : Here is a reproducible example.

Code for the original functions can be found [here](https://github.com/cran/arsenal/blob/master/R/tableby.stats.R%0A).

So this is what I have now :

```
data<-NULL
data$Visit2<-c(rep("Responder",121),rep("Not Responder",29),rep("Responder",4),rep("Not Responder",47))
data$Group<-c(rep("Tx",150),rep("No Tx",51))
data<-as.data.frame(data)


library(arsenal)
my_controls <- tableby.control(test = F,total = F,  cat.stats = c("countpct" ,"binomCI"), conf.level = 0.95)

summary(tableby(Group ~ Visit2,
                data = data, 
                control = my_controls),
                digits=2, digits.p=3, digits.pct=1)

# Results :
|                                |   No Tx (N=51)    |    Tx (N=150)     |
|:-------------------------------|:-----------------:|:-----------------:|
|**Visit2**                      |                   |                   |
|                  Not Responder |    47 (92.2%)     |    29 (19.3%)     |
|                  Responder     |     4 (7.8%)      |    121 (80.7%)    |
|                  Not Responder | 0.92 (0.81, 0.98) | 0.19 (0.13, 0.27) |
|                  Responder     | 0.08 (0.02, 0.19) | 0.81 (0.73, 0.87) |







And this is what I want :

|                 |        No Tx (N=51)       |        Tx (N=150)        |
|:----------------|:-------------------------:|:------------------------:|
|**Visit2**                                   |                          |                 
|   Not Responder |  47 (92.2%) [81.1, 97.8]  |  29 (19.3%) [13.3, 26.6] |   
|   Responder     |   4 (7.8%) [2.2, 18.9]    | 121 (80.7%) [73.4, 86.7] |
|
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I added an example.